# C# Windows Form disappears suddenly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I am using C# + VSTS2008 + .Net 2.0 to develop a Windows Forms application. In button1 event handler of Form1, I create Form2, then Form2 appears. Then when trigger event handler of button2 of Form2 (button2 is Form2's UI button element), after executing button2 event handler, Form2 will disappear. Here is part of my code which creates Form2. Any ideas what is wrong to cause Form2 disappear?

```
// button1 belongs to Form1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2("www.google.com");
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that's handling Button2_Click?

Comment: Post your button2 event handler

Comment: The event handler of button2 is empty. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: @George2 My answer is a possible reason the dialog is being dismissed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150516/c-windows-form-disappears-suddenly/1150562#1150562

Comment: Thanks Colin, I like your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form2 is being opened as a dialog. Could the button being pressed also be defined as the  [CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) (The CancelButton property will be on form2). Doing that will automatically dismiss the dialog when the event handlers have completed.

Comment: As an interesting side note, setting the AcceptButton will *not* automatically dismiss the form. It may seem inconsequent, but is logical I guess; if we cancel we usually just want to go away, while accepting may include some work before we leave, and may lead to us wanting the dialog to stay (if some validation fails for instance).

Answer (score 3):

Without more details it's impossible to say for sure, but if button2 in `Form2` has a value assigned to the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) property, this will cause the form to hide automatically when the button is clicked. Open Form2 in the designer, select the button and check in the property grid. If the DialogResult property is anything else than "`None`", this is expected behaviour.

From the MSDN documentation of the Button.DialogResult property:

> If the `DialogResult` for this property
>   is set to anything other than `None`,
>   and if the parent form was displayed
>   through the `ShowDialog` method,
>   clicking the button closes the parent
>   form without your having to hook up
>   any events. The form's `DialogResult`
>   property is then set to the
>   `DialogResult` of the button when the
>   button is clicked.

Comment: The event handler of button2 is empty. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Read my answer again; it's not about the event handler, it's about the DialogResult property of button2. But if the event handler is empty, it strengthens my suspicion that it is the DialogResult property that causes the behaviour.

Comment: I have checked that the dialog result of button 2 is None, is that expected value?

Comment: Sorry Fredrik, I find the root cause, I set button2 to be the CancelButton of Form2, does that cause the Form2 to disappear?

Comment: Yes, as Colin suggests below, that may also cause the Form to disappear. You should mark that as the accepted answer ;o)

Comment: @George2 Setting the CancelButton property on the form  will cause the form to disappear when the associated button is pressed.

Comment: @Colin: ha ha, with your comment there I almost come out as clairvoyant :o)

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Good catch on the possibility of setting the DialogResult. Just tried it and it dismissed the dialog. Never knew that. I always set it then closed the dialog myself.

Comment: @Fredrik Yes, I see what you mean. :)